# Calculating and converting prefix to infix

Tags: recursion, converters, prefix, infix-notation, stack

I'm having some serious problems writing a program that convert prefix to infix. I have already written 2 programs which use stacks but do so differently - one used two stacks, the other used one with a recursive method. But I'm still having problems correctly doing it since the requirements demands that it use two stacks (operand and operator) and use a recursive method. I'm having serious problems visualizing both of those requirements together. Does anyone knows what the algorithm would look like? if i could simply have an algorithm, it would really be a life saver.
Thank you

Comment: If you can do it without recursion, then by all means do it without recursion. There's no need to ADD recursion to an existing algorithm for no reason.

Answer (score 2):

This does it.

```
(define (prefix->infix pre)
  (cond ((list? pre)
         (assert (= 3 (length pre)))
         (let ((operator (list-ref pre 0))
               (operand1 (list-ref pre 1))
               (operand2 (list-ref pre 2)))
           (list (prefix->infix operand1)
                 operator
                 (prefix->infix operand2))))
        (else pre)))

> (prefix->infix '(+ 1 2))
(1 + 2)
> (prefix->infix '(+ 1 (* 2 3)))
(1 + (2 * 3))
> (prefix->infix '(+ (/ 1 4) (* 2 3)))
((1 / 4) + (2 * 3))
```

It doesn't use 'stacks' explicitly (but the recursions use a call stack).