# Infix to Prefix conversion scheme

Tags: scheme, prefix, infix-notation

I'm trying to figure out how to convert an infix expression to prefix in Scheme.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931996/calculating-and-converting-prefix-to-infix) post which does what I want but in the opposite direction. What changes when going from infix->prefix instead of prefix->infix?

Edit: I forgot to mention I need to account and handle for variables. For example the input

`'(2 + 3 * a ^ 5 + b)`

Answer (score 2):

It's rather trivial to modify the algorithm you link to:

```
(define (infix->prefix lst)
  (cond
    ((list? lst) 
     (unless (= 3 (length lst)) (error "not 3 elements"))
     (let ((operand1 (car lst))
           (operator (cadr lst))
           (operand2 (caddr lst)))
       (list operator
             (infix->prefix operand1)
             (infix->prefix operand2))))
    (else lst)))
```

Testing:

```
> (infix->prefix '(1 + 2))
'(+ 1 2)
> (infix->prefix '(1 + (2 * 3)))
'(+ 1 (* 2 3))
> (infix->prefix '((1 / 4) + (2 * 3)))
'(+ (/ 1 4) (* 2 3))
```

This is not a general algorithm though; if you need something more elaborate then please show some examples of conversions you need to do.

**EDIT** Here's an example code that works for longer expressions but doesn't implement operator precedence:

```
(define (infix->prefix lst)
  (if (list? lst)
      (if (null? (cdr lst))
          ; list with one element -> return element
          (infix->prefix (car lst))
          ; list with more than one element
          (list (cadr lst)
                (infix->prefix (car lst))
                (infix->prefix (cddr lst))))
      ; not a list -> return element
      lst))
```

Testing:

```
> (infix->prefix '(2 + 3 * a ^ 5 + b))
'(+ 2 (* 3 (^ a (+ 5 b))))
```

Comment: Yes this is what I need, but I forgot to add in the description I need to also account for possible variables. For example how would I parse the string '(2 + 3 * a ^ 5 + b).

Comment: Variables are not problem, for example `(infix->prefix '(2 + (3 * a)))` will yield `'(+ 2 (* 3 a))`. But what is not accounted for is 1) expressions of more than 3 elements, and 2) precedence of operators. So please add a few useful examples (input as well as output).

Comment: IMHO, the above program cannot handle such expression as "(infix->prefix '(1 + (2 + 3)))", and it will produce result as "(+ 1 (2 + 3))".    But we can make a minor adjustment:   (if (null? (cdr lst))
          ; list with one element -> return element
          (car lst)  ======> (if (null? (cdr lst))
          ; list with one element -> return element
          (infix-prefix (car lst))